# How to Clear Form AFTER Rails Validation

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, submit

I have a form that I would like the clear on submit. The trouble I am having is that one of my form fields has a "presence: true" validation. This validation is executed after form has cleared, therefore creating an error and preventing the form data from saving. How should I go about clearing the form only after the validation has occurred?

```js
$(document).on('ready', function(){

 $('.bagelType').on('click', function(){
  $('#order_item_bagel_type').val($(this).data("bagel"));
 })

 $('#new_order_item').on('submit', function(){
  $('#order_item_bagel_type').val("");
 });

});
```

```html
<%= form_for order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :bagel_type, value:"" %>
 <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: after form submit. You want the fields to be empty. is it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[value="sbumit"]').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').removeAttr('required');
});
```

Whenever the submit button is clicked this `js` code will run and the form associated text field's **required** validation will be removed.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

you can create a create.js erb file

```
<% if @order_item.errors.any? %>
  do some stuff here
<%else%>
   write hide functionality here 
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form_id")[0].reset()
```

It will reset your complete form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myForm').trigger("reset");
```